# Problems with user defined constructors in C++

Tags: c++, class, object

Im having issues with a class constructors that i define. my .cpp's and .h compile on there own but once i try to use them in a main and construct a class it throws errors.

ive read about how not properly defining a user created constructor may cause the same error but im positive that everything is correct.

joust.cpp

```
#include "joust.h"
  2 //create class construct for knight class
  3 //set his name stam and put him on a horse
  4 knight::knight (string n) :  equipped_wep(5,5,"Basic Blade"){
  5   name = n;
  6   stamina = 100;
  7   mounted = true;
  8 }
  9 
 10 void knight::show_stats() {
 11   if (stamina) {
 12     cout << name << " is not exhausted (stamina="<< stamina<< ") and is moun    ted" << endl;
 13   } else {
 14       cout << name <<  " has passed out from exhaustion" << endl;
 15   }
 16 }
 17 void knight::show_wep() {
 18   cout << name << " is using " << equipped_wep.display_wep() << endl;
 19 }
 20 
 21 void knight::equip_weapon(weapon wep) {
 22   equipped_wep = wep;
```

joust.h

```
 13 #ifndef JOUST_H
 14 #define JOUST_H
 15 
 16 #include <iostream>
 17 #include <fstream>
 18 #include <vector>
 19 
 20 using namespace std;
 21 
 22 class weapon {
 23   public:
 24     weapon(float = 1, float = 1, string = "base");
 25     void set(float, float);
 26     string display_wep();
 27   private:
 28     float effectivness;
 29     float weight;
 30     string name;
 31 };
 32 
 33 class knight {
 34   public:
 35     knight( string = "base");
 36     void show_stats();
 37     void show_wep();
 38     void equip_weapon(weapon wep);
 39   private:
 40     weapon equipped_wep;
 41     string name;
 42     int stamina;
 43     bool mounted;
 44 };
 45 
 46 
 47 #endif
```

test.cpp

```
 #include "joust.h"
  2 
  3 int main() {
  4   //knight jim("Rob the Third");
  5   //jim.show_stats();
  6   weapon c(15,12,"jard");
  7 
  8   return 0;
  9 }
```

makefile

```
 test: test.o joust.o
  2         g++ -std=c++11 joust.o test.o -o test
  3 test.o: test.cpp joust.h
  4         g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
  5 joust.o: joust.cpp joust.h
  6         g++ -std=c++11 -c joust.cpp
  7 clean:
  8         rm -f joust.o
```

It should of just created a weapon object bust instead threw this error

```
make
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "weapon::weapon(float, float, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in test-501f47.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [test.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Why no `-c ` for compiling `test.cpp` ?

Comment: Please don't include line numbers in your [mcve], a good example should be possibly to copy-paste for us to try and replicate your problem, without needing modifications. If you need to mark out a specific line, then add a comment on that line.

Comment: side note: for this ctor `weapon(float = 1, float = 1, string = "base");` give a name to parameters, possibly different from class members `weapon(float effect= 1, float wgh= 1, string theName = "base");`: it will semplify your life when writing code calling that ctor/method. Use some suitable naming convention for member variables, a common choice is to use a trailing  _, e.g. `weight_`

Answer (score 0):

There are *two* problems that you have:

1. First you need to build all source file together, or to create object files from each source file that you then link together.
2. The second error is that you don't define (implement) the `weapon` constructor anywhere.

The first problem is solved by adding the `-c` flag when building the source files. The `-c` flags tells GCC to create object files (the files ending in `.o`). You have it when building the `joust.cpp` source file, but seem to have forgotten it for the `test.cpp` source file.

The second problem should be pretty obvious how to solve: Implement the constructor function.